# How to get state of mat-expansion-panel?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

```html
<mat-expansion-panel #linkServices>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
      <mat-icon>request_quote</mat-icon>Services</mat-panel-title>
    <mat-panel-description>
      Add a service
    </mat-panel-description>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  ...
```

I want to know if my panel is opened or closed. This is how I tried it with a ViewChild():

```js
console.log(this.linkServices.nativeElement.expanded);
```

but I get the error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'expanded')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage `opened` and `closed` output events:

```js
public isOpened: boolean;
```

```html
<mat-expansion-panel (opened)="isOpened = true" (closed)="isOpened = false">
  ...
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Comment: You probably mean `public isOpened: boolean;`. However, great! Just what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: can we do this without a declaration in ts?